# Using jquery to toggle a CSS property and also animate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below code:

```
$('#button').click(function () { 
    $('#divName').animate({
        top: 90%,
    }, 1000, function(){
    });  
});
```

When the button is clicked, it sets the top property for the DIV to 90%.

When I click the button again, I went to revert the CSS back to its original (50%).

How can I do this?

My attempt which seems to work but seems messy:

```
var state = false;

$('#button').click(function () { 
    if (state) {
        state = false;
        $('#divName').animate({
        top: '50%',
        }, 1000, function(){
      });
    } else if (state == false){
        state = false;
        $('#divName').animate({
        top: '90%',
       }, 1000, function(){
     });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions). With jQuery just toggle a class.

```js
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#divName').toggleClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#divName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  transition: top 1s linear;
}

.animate {
  top: 90% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Press</button>
<div class="container">
  <div id="divName"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could improve this with some minor changes:

```js
var state = false;

$('#button').click(function() {
  percent = state ? 50 : 90
  $('#divName').animate({
    top: percent + '%',
  }, 1000, function() {});
  state = !state;
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="button">clickme</p>

<div id="divName">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

here is one way to do it by removing the style added by jQuery

```js
var div = $('#divName');
$('#button').click(function () {
  var style = div.attr("style");
  if(style && style.includes("top")){
    div.attr("style", style.replace(/top:[^;]+;/,""));
  }else{
    div.css("top", "90%");
  }
});
```

```css
#divName{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%; /*you need to give an init value to top*/
  transition: top 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click me</button>
<div id="divName"></div>
```

Comment: and now you just make it more messy.

Comment: @ths how comes ?

Comment: using regular expressions, fetching the style attribute is unnecessary, more complexity.

Comment: it is necessary in my answer.